# Remove header in latex

Tags: header-footer

In my document: http://www.mediafire.com/file/fkuiis9y7agwzcq/FullProceeding.rar

How to remove header of pages 2, 21, 43, 55? Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question. Much more people may be willing to help you if they don't have to visit some third party site and download a .rar file of unknown origin.

Comment: Moreover, some readers of your posting may find themselves behind firewalls which block all access to social media sites (such as mediafire.com). Why make it difficult, or even impossible, for these readers to try and help you?

Comment: Connected to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758923/clear-header-single-page